# Magento : White Space Around Sku

Tags: product, price, sku, edit

I am facing an error while updating  product price because of extra white space around sku code. Any one know how can I remove that space from all  product sku code.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Its magento CE version 1.9.2x

Comment: Did you get solution for this issue?

Comment: No still not when i am trying to run that file on browser it's only loading and loading no result can you help me in this ?

Comment: Can you let me know how much number of products you have in your setup?

Comment: It's near around 2000+

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It may help you what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can remove whitespace from SKU values. Create a new `php` file e.g. `updateSku.php` in your Magento root folder and put this code in it. Then run file with URL : `YOUR_MAGENTO_HOST/updateSku.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
?>
<html><head><title>Trim Product SKU</title><style type="text/css">h1,thead{text-align:center}.result-table td{padding:3px 0 3px 15px}body{margin:0 auto;width:65%}.main-div,.result-table{width:100%;box-shadow:0 1px 11px #000;float:left}h1{margin-top:10px;text-decoration:underline}.main-div{margin:0 auto;border:1px outset #fff}.result-table{margin:5px auto 0;font-size:13px}.suggestion-from{clear:both;float:left;font-size:11px;line-height:26px;margin-left:5px;position:absolute}form{padding:30px 30px 0}.search-button{float:right;margin-top:25px}thead{font-size:20px}</style></head><body><h1>Trim Product SKU</h1><div class="main-div"><form action="" method="post"><table><tr><td><label><?php echo "Product from";?></label><td><input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['from']))?$_POST['from']:"" ?>"/><label class="suggestion-from">Product From</label></td></tr><tr><td><label><?php echo "Product to";?></label><td><input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['to']))?$_POST['to']:"" ?>"/><label class="suggestion-from">Product To</label></td></tr><tr></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input class="search-button" type="submit" title="Trim" value="Trim"/></td></tr></table></form></div></body></html>   
<?php 
if($_POST){
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    echo "<table border='1' class='result-table'><thead><tr><td colspan='3'>Import Data</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Product Id</td><td>Trimmed SKU</td></tr>";
    trimSKU($from, $to);
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
$i = 0;
function trimSKU($from, $to){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $product){
        $i++;
        if($i > $to || $i < $from) { continue; };
        $sku = trim($product->getSku());
        if($product->getId()){
            $product->setSku($sku)->save();
            echo "<tr><td>". $product->getId()."</td><td>".$product->getSKU()."</td></tr>";
        }
    } 
}

?>
```

When you run the file, it will give you a form like below.
[image]
Add Product from as the starting point like **1**
Add Product to as Ending point like **100**
 Click on Trim button. It will trim 1 to 100 products. Once these products gets trimmed, start with values **101** to **200**. 
 It may happen that due to server limitations, the script may not run well. With this file you can update product SKUs in chunks. I will suggest you to keep chunks of **100** products at one time.

**UPDATE**
I have checked the script execution time and found that if you change your indexes mode to **Manual Update** the script will run much faster.

> Execution time with indexes "Update on Save" : 208.79583716393
>   Execution time with indexes "Manual Update" : 152.2172369957

Answer (score 0):

Via direct SQL with simple output messages.  Extremely quick.  Set $path to local.xml correctly. Remember to re-index after running.

```
<?php

global $conn;
global $db;

// Set path to local.xml correctly
$path = "../app/etc/local.xml"; 

$count = 0;


$xml = simplexml_load_file($path, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
if(is_object($xml)):

    createDatabaseConnection($xml);//Create Connection

    $data = _getSKUs();

    foreach ($data as $productId=>$sku):

        $skuTrim = trim($sku);

        if ($sku == $skuTrim):
            continue;
        endif;

        $count ++;

        if (_updateSku($productId,$skuTrim)):

            echo "<p>ID=>". $productId." SKU=> ".$sku." White Space removed</p>";

        else:

            echo "<p>ERROR ID=>". $productId." SKU=> ".$sku." NOT UPDATED</p>";
        endif;

    endforeach;

    if ($count == 0):
        echo "<p>NO SKUs to TRIM</p>";
    endif;


endif;

$conn->close(); // Close database connection


/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/


function createDatabaseConnection($xml) {
    global $conn;
    global $db;

    $db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
    $db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
    $db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
    $db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
    $db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;

    $conn = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['name']);

    // check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error):
        trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    endif;
}




function _getSKUs(){ //Get ALL product skus
    global $conn;
    global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT sku,entity_id  FROM ".$db['pref']."catalog_product_entity";

        if ($result = $conn->query($sql)):

        if ($result->num_rows):

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
                $data[$row['entity_id']]= $row['sku']; // Load data into array      
            endwhile;
        endif;
    endif;

    return $data;
}

function _updateSku($productId,$sku){

    global $conn;
    global $db;

        $sql = 'UPDATE '.$db['pref'].'catalog_product_entity SET sku = "'.$sku.'" WHERE entity_id = '.$productId;        

        if ($result = $conn->query($sql)):
        return true;
    endif;

    return false;

}
?>
```